# Ajax retornar um loop de resultados

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Estou fazendo um sistema financeiro com ajax, tanto receitas quanto despesas tem "descrições" e para editar as informações de uma receita eu chamo as informações dela mas eu tenho que puxar as descrições tbm.
O porém é que eu uso append no front-end pra criar essas descrições e pego o numero de linhas geradas ali e faço um loop no php que grava no banco. Agora tenho que recuperar essas linhas e botar nesse append novamente.

Fiz funcionar para puxar os dados únicos, mas para puxar as descrições do jeito que fiz não esta funcionando...(o ajax das descrições esta dentro do "success" do ajax da receita pelo certo)

Desculpa pelo tamanho da questão...

[image: esquema de como funciona]

[image: front-end]

Arquivo php que o ajax chama...

```
<?php
include_once("../database/Database.class.php");

$database = new Database();

$idReceita = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM cnt_receita_descricao WHERE id_receita = '".$idReceita."'";
$resultado = $database->conexao->query($sql);

$linha = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$numero_de_linhas = $resultado->rowCount();

if ($numero_de_linhas > 0){

for ($i = 0; $i <$numero_de_linhas; $i++) {

  $dadoReceitaDescricao[$i] = array(
    'numero_de_linhas' => $numero_de_linhas,
    'decricao' => $linha_descricao['descricao'],
    'complemento' => $linha_descricao['complemento'],
    'valor_unitario' => $linha_descricao['valor_unitario'],
    'todos_meses' => $linha_descricao['todos_meses'],
    'numero_de_meses' => $linha_descricao['numero_de_meses']
  );
}
}

echo json_encode($dadoReceitaDescricao[$i]);
?>
```

Script ajax...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function pegarIdDaReceitaEditar(id){
 var idReceita = id;
 alert(idReceita);
 $.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "buscarDadosReceita.php?id="+idReceita,
 success: function( response ){
   var dadosReceita = jQuery.parseJSON( response );

   $("#dadoDaReceita").val(dadosReceita.dadoDaReceita);
   // alert("teste01R-R");

   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "buscarDadosReceitaDescricao.php?id="+idReceita,
     success: function( response ){
       var dadosReceitaDescricao = jQuery.parseJSON( response );

       $("#numero_de_linhas").val(dadosReceitaDescricao.numero_de_linhas);
       // alert("teste01R-D");

       for($i=0; $i<$dadosReceitaDescricao.numero_de_linhas; $i++){

$("#dadoDeDescricaoDaReceita"+$i).val(dadosReceitaDescricao.dadoDeDescricaoDaReceita);
       }
     }
   });

 }
 });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Substitua os prints de codigo por texto na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que a variavel `$linha_descricao` não existe, o certo é `$linha`, pois os resultados da sua query estão aqui: `$linha = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

```
$dadoReceitaDescricao[$i] = array(
    'numero_de_linhas' => $numero_de_linhas,
    'decricao' => $linha['descricao'], // <-- aqui
    'complemento' => $linha['complemento'], // <-- aqui
    'valor_unitario' => $linha['valor_unitario'], // <-- aqui
    'todos_meses' => $linha['todos_meses'], // <-- aqui
    'numero_de_meses' => $linha['numero_de_meses'] // <-- aqui
  );
```

Além disso tem um outro erro. Nesta linha:

```
$resultado = $database->conexao->query($sql);
```

O certo é:

```
$resultado = $database->query($sql);
```

O erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numero_de_linhas' of null` acontece no JS, explicando que essa variável veio nula, pois houve esses erros anteriores na sua conexão com o banco.

Comment: me passei nesse detalhe, obrigado... porém ele ainda me diz "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'numero_de_linhas' of null
"

Comment: @GustavoSamuelMarcolin tem um outro erro. Vou editar.

Comment: @GustavoSamuelMarcolin deu certo?

Comment: @GustavoSamuelMarcolin acho que vc deveria postas a classe database... Apague as informaçoes do banco e poste a classe na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

@AndreiCoelho consegui resolver a questão estava com varios detalhes faltando

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function pegarIdDaReceitaEditar(id){
var idReceita = id;
alert(idReceita);
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "buscarDadosReceita.php?id="+idReceita,
success: function( response ){
var dadosReceita = jQuery.parseJSON( response );

$("#dadoDaReceita").val(dadosReceita.dadoDaReceita);
// alert("teste01R-R");

$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "buscarDadosReceitaDescricao.php?id="+idReceita,
 success: function( response ){

   if(response){
   var dadosReceitaDescricao = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
   //console.warn(dadosReceitaDescricao);

   $("#numero_de_linhas").val(dadosReceitaDescricao.numero_de_linhas);
   // alert("teste01R-D");

   for($i=0; $i<$dadosReceitaDescricao.numero_de_linhas; $i++){

   $("#dadoDeDescricaoDaReceita"+$i)
   .val(dadosReceitaDescricao.dadoDeDescricaoDaReceita);

   $.each(dadosReceitaDescricao, function(i, descricao) {

     var descCallB = $("string com os dados da descricao");

   }

  }else{
     console.warn('erro: sem resposta.');
  }
   }
 }
});

}
});
 }
</script>
```

E no arquico php pouca coisa mudei...

```
<?php
 include_once("../database/Database.class.php");

 $database = new Database();

 $idReceita = $_GET['id'];

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM cnt_receita_descricao WHERE id_receita = '".$idReceita."'";
 $resultado = $database->conexao->query($sql);

 $numero_de_linhas = $resultado->rowCount();

 if ($numero_de_linhas > 0){

  for ($i = 0; $i <$numero_de_linhas; $i++) {

   $linha_descricao = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   $dadosReceitaDescricao[$i] = array(
    'numero_de_linhas' => $numero_de_linhas,
    'id_descricao' => $linha_descricao['id_descricao'],
    'decricao' => $linha_descricao['descricao'],
    'complemento' => $linha_descricao['complemento'],
    'valor_unitario' => $linha_descricao['valor_unitario'],
    'todos_meses' => $linha_descricao['todos_meses'],
    'numero_de_meses' => $linha_descricao['numero_de_meses']
  );
 }
}

echo json_encode($dadosReceitaDescricao);
?>
```

Desse jeito esta funcionando como quero. Obrigado!

Comment: Legal Gustavo, comente os detalhes que estavam faltando, poderá ajudar outras pessoas com problema parecido.